# Converting numeric character vectors to numeric leaving non-numeric character vectors unchanged in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, vector, character

In `data` below, all variables (columns) are character strings. However, some of them are real character strings (`Z`), others are in reality numeric vectors that have been forced into a character string (`N`).

In general (`data` below is obviously is toy), how can I return variables like `N` into numeric but leave other variables like `Z` unchanged?

```
data <- data.frame(Z = letters[1:3], N = as.character(-1:1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this needs to be automatic, use `type.convert` which picks up the column type based on the values and return the appropriate type.  Note that this may not work if there are any values in the column have mixed type i.e. `c(1, 0, 'a')` which remains as  `character` because of the type precedence

```
type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: A [question of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71489264/16762740).