# Find and rename columns in a set of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr

I have 4 data.frames (`d1,...d4`). Some of these data.frames have more columns than others some less.

I wonder how to automatically find **any** of the colnames: `"emmean","SE","t.ratio","df","p.value","lower.CL","upper.CL"`
and then rename them to:
`"Mean","SE","t","Df","p-value","Lower","Upper"`, respectively?

ps. We leave all other columns untouched.
Note that I don't have a list of data.frames. I may get only one of the data.frames below.

```
d1="
training_hr time      emmean    SE     df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
  23.145    Baseline     NA    NA     NA       NA       NA      NA      NA
  23.145    Post-test1  0.428 0.134 70.000    0.161    0.695   3.199   0.002
  23.145    Post-test2    NA    NA     NA       NA       NA      NA      NA"
d1 = read.table(text=d1,h=T)


d2="
  training_hr        time emmean    SE     df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio
      23.145    Baseline     NA    NA     NA       NA       NA      NA
      23.145 Post-test1  0.428 0.134 70.000    0.161    0.695   3.199
      23.145 Post-test2     NA    NA     NA       NA       NA      NA"
d2= read.table(text=d2,h=T)

d3="
  training_hr        time emmean    SE     df  t.ratio p.value
      23.145    Baseline     NA    NA     NA  NA      NA
      23.145 Post-test1  0.428 0.134 70.000  3.199   0.002
      23.145 Post-test2     NA    NA     NA  NA      NA"
d3=read.table(text=d3,h=T)

d4="
  training_hr   emmean    SE     df     t.ratio   p.value
      23.145   NA        NA     NA     NA        NA
      23.145   0.428     0.134 70.000  3.199     0.002
      23.145   NA        NA     NA     NA        NA"
d4=read.table(text=d4,h=T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Data Table**

You can use `setnames` from `data.table`, which takes the old and new names as separate lists. Whereas with `tidyverse`, you have to give the old and new names together (e.g., `Mean = "emmean"`). But note `setnames` will change your original dataframe (changes them by reference).

```
library(data.table)

setnames(df1, old = c("emmean","SE","t.ratio","df","p.value","lower.CL","upper.CL"),
                          new = c("Mean","SE","t","Df","p-value","Lower","Upper"), skip_absent=TRUE)
```

*Output*

```
d1

  training_hr       time  Mean    SE Df Lower Upper     t p-value
1      23.145   Baseline    NA    NA NA    NA    NA    NA      NA
2      23.145 Post-test1 0.428 0.134 70 0.161 0.695 3.199   0.002
3      23.145 Post-test2    NA    NA NA    NA    NA    NA      NA
```

---

**Tidyverse**

With `tidyverse`, you can create an external vector with all of the possible name changes, then use `any` inside `rename`.

```
library(tidyverse)

lookup <- c(Mean = "emmean", SE = "SE", t = "t.ratio", DF = "df", "p-value" = "p.value", Lower = "lower.CL", Upper = "upper.CL")

d1 %>%
  rename(any_of(lookup))

#  training_hr       time  Mean    SE DF Lower Upper     t p-value
#1      23.145   Baseline    NA    NA NA    NA    NA    NA      NA
#2      23.145 Post-test1 0.428 0.134 70 0.161 0.695 3.199   0.002
#3      23.145 Post-test2    NA    NA NA    NA    NA    NA      NA
```

---

For several dataframes, you could put the dataframes into a list then use a combination of `map` from `purrr` and `setnames` from `data.table`. This will also update all of the original dataframes by reference (i.e., `d1`, `d2`, ...).

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

df.list <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4)

map(df.list, ~ setnames(.x, old = c("emmean","SE","t.ratio","df","p.value","lower.CL","upper.CL"),
                          new = c("Mean","SE","t","Df","p-value","Lower","Upper"), skip_absent=TRUE))
```

Comment: thanks for letting me know my answer wouldn't work for all dataframes! I deleted my answer since I think it added too many steps to have to check each data frame for the existence of column names

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Is a fully tidyverse solution possible? BTW, I don't have a list of data.frame. The output of the function that I work with could give one of the data.frames shown above.